# How can I see the filename for the Default Page is being loaded by the browser?

Tags: default, web-hosting

if I browse to TheSite.com/

The default page it loads depends on the Default page order.

So Assume the root has:

- default.htm
- default.aspx

Without knowing the above order, and what pages are in the root, how can I view the filename for the default page loaded into the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the server is setup you could just try TheSite.com/index.html (and the other various default options).  But it won't tell you the filename anywhere if the URL doesn't specify it.

Additionally, just because a web server has "index.html" as the page, doesn't mean there is a file physically on the server called index.html